# How do I reference a parent variable in JavaScript? like _parent.myvar

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I have variables set in the main root of the script

```
var name="blah";
```

I need to refer to this from within a function w/o PASSING it directly in its parameters. I could set the variables in the global scope w/o using "var' initializer, and that has worked for my function.  But, I still need to know how to do this for similar reasons.

In Flash (AS2/AS3) it's as simple as `_root.myvar` or `_parent.myvar`

in JS?

sample:

```
var name="blah";
var sex="m";
templateMe('name,sex'); // declared the actual NAME of the var not the var itself
```

then.. templateMe function simply uses the "string" passed into the function as both variable name and its corresponding value

meaning the 'name' string becomes

```
var name=eval(name)
```

here's a part of the function:

```
vars_r =  vars.split(",");
r_count = vars_r.length;

if(r_count < 1 ){
    return template;
}

var i=0;
var needles = new Array();
var replacements  = new Array();;
for(i=0; i < 2; i++){ //ti <-- use own i counter coz it conflicts w/ global i
    needles.push("{{"+ vars_r[i] + "}}");
    replacements.push( eval( vars_r[i]) );

}
```

etc...

hope this makes more sense now

Comment: If the variable is set outside a function, you can access it directly even if it was declared with `var`. That only makes a difference for variables declared inside a function.

Comment: Variables are automatically available in nested functions via closures. If that doesn't answer the question, show an example of what you're trying to do, as the current question is very unclear.

Comment: adding / editing my original post

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you do not need to pass the variables at all.

The variables are already global, so you can just reference them directly.

For example:

```
var value1 = "some value";  /* these variables are global, so you can refer to them from anywhere in your script */
var value2 = 25;            /* ********************************************* */
someFunction();
```

And someFunction would look like this:

```
function someFunction() {
    var newValue = value2 + 3; 
    alert(newValue); /* Alerts 28. */
    alert(value1); /* Alerts 'some value'. */
}
```

If you need a place to learn JavaScript, [webplatform.org](http://webplatform.org) would probably be [a good place to start](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/javascript).

Hope this helps!

Comment: yep but that was kind off an example. i do need to still refer to parent function's vars in my actual situation.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are properties of the `window` object. So, if you need to reference a global variable when you have its name in a string variable called `varname`, you can use `window[varname]`, like this:

```
var foo = 'bar';
var varname = 'foo';
console.log( window[varname] );
```

which prints:

```
bar
```

As Stephen points out, there are likely to be better ways to tackle the overall problem, but this approach works fine if you really need to access a global variable this way.

Looking at your code, I think you would replace this line:

```
replacements.push( eval( vars_r[i]) );
```

with:

```
replacements.push( window[ vars_r[i] ] );
```

although I'm not sure I understand what this code is doing. In any case, `window[varname]` is a lot better than `eval(varname)`.

Comment: thanks mate, i see your point... but .. hmm. i wish i could post the whole script here but it may just tire you guys out.. hence i simply wanted to know how to reference to a variable on the parent scope , not necessarily the global/root/window scope..


a variable is created on the ROOT, passed into a function, w/c inside a function a new set of variables are created, and NOT PASSED into the FUNCTION inside it, but rather, the names of the variable (String literral) is passed in CSV format into that function, that 3rd level function then parses the CSV and grabs the VARIABLE from the parent.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you have to have these items all as individual variables? That is what's causing all the trouble here. Instead of `var name="blah"; var sex="m";` could you use `var values = { name:"blah", sex:"m" };`? If you did that, everything would be much easier and your code will be a lot cleaner and simpler. Using an object with properties is really the JavaScript way to do this, instead of dealing with a bunch of individual variables.

Comment: i understand what you mean and i did try to find an easier way.. but i found nothing is much more simple, in this case, than just refering to a parent variable.. 

one good example, i have here a templating function.. the template HTML contains variable names that is meant to be replaced.. like "{{name}}" w/c the function replaces w/ the contents of the actual variable "name" w/c was CREATED in the parent function, NOT THE ROOT/WINDOW.. why? because that function needs to do specific logic to set name= variable right. now all i have to do is makeTemplate('name,sex,age,code);

Comment: i also tried to do the array way, passing an associative array into the template function instead of a CSV.. but JS sucks at this.. unlike php.. it's so easy to count values in arrays and get multid associative index, as well as index count of an array and all that. i just found the use of array for this purpose in JS language too cumbersome.. so a simple CSV of variables i wana target w/ ALREADY exists anway is the way to go, the problem is, it's on the _PARENT level w/c again, is another shortcoming of JS it seems = there is no way to reference to _parent.. it's either root or not.. sucks